# Iterate search for multiple strings between two files in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I feel like this should be easy, but I'm inexperienced and flubbing it. Basically, I have two files with similar data but formatted differently. I want to read File 1 and find the key data in each line. Then I want to take the key data and see if it exists in any line in File 2.

For example, File01 contains lines that look like this:

```
- September 08, 2014 at 06:03PM - Task 1  @done 

- September 08, 2014 at 06:21PM - Task 2  @done 

- September 09, 2014 at 08:04AM - Task 3  @done 

- September 09, 2014 at 08:28AM - Task 4  @done
```

And File02 contains lines that look like this:

```
2014-09-08,18:03,Entry,Tag,Completed: Task 1,Location,10001,City,ST,United States,99.999999,-99.99999
2014-09-09,08:04,Entry,Tag,Completed: Task 3,Location,10001,City,ST,United States,99.999999,-99.99999
2014-09-09,08:28,Entry,Tag,Completed: Task 4,Location,10001,City,ST,United States,99.999999,-99.99999
```

In this example, Task 2 is missing. So I'm trying to find the task item, see if it exists in the second file, and if it doesn't, then print the task that is missing—in this case, "Task 2".

Here is how I have been finding the task names:

```
f1 = File.readlines('/Users/path/to/File01.txt')
f1.each do |line|
    /-\s(?<t>.*)\s-\s(?<data>.*)(?<end>@done)/ =~ line
    if data != nil
    puts data
    end
end
```

The grep search is fine and yielding the results I need, but I just can't figure out how to take this data and then search for it in the second file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you post two example files and the expected output?

Comment: Added more detail to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your corpus, you can break your logic down into tasks to search for, and a log file to search. For example:

```
tasks = File.read('File01.txt').scan /Task \d+/
log   = File.read 'File02.txt'
tasks.each { |t| puts "Task missing: #{t}" if log !~ /#{t}(?=,)/ }
```

This scans your input file for a list of tasks, then scans the log file for a match for each task using a positive lookahead to ensure you're matching the correct task number (e.g. so Task 1 doesn't also match Task 11). For example, your corpus yields the following result:

> Task missing: Task 2

Comment: Elegant! I knew I was missing something obvious. Works like a charm once you add parentheses after the .scan call on line 1 and the .read on line 2.

Comment: @craigeley Glad you found it helpful. What version of Ruby are you using? I'm using MRI 2.1.2, and the parser doesn't complain about the lack of parenthesis for terminal arguments for me. I just tried, and I get the same successful results with Rubinius and JRuby, too. Different Ruby versions may parse it differently, though, and one can never go wrong by adding parentheses where appropriate. If there's a major portability issue, though, let me know so I can improve the answer for future visitors. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using the system Ruby on Mac 10.9.5, which is currently at 2.0.0p481

Comment: Just tested on OS X with a system Ruby of 2.0.0p451. No parentheses were necessary for the terminal arguments. Unless you're appending method chains, the example above should work as posted. If you're still having problems with it, please post it as a separate question and I'll be glad to help further.